# right aligning text in android with single line

Tags: android, textview, alignment

I want to align text to right its working fine but if the text is small its change the line but i want it a single line and move text to right.
i am doing it like this

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spinner"
        android:background="@drawable/tm_bubbles_blue"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/app_name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subject"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/message_text"
        android:layout_below="@+id/message_text" />
```

[image]

Comment: did you used singleline property??

Comment: use android:singleLine="true" to restrict the text only in one line ...

Comment: single line add dots in the end, i do not want any dots, i have to move text right if it move to second line

Comment: @FrankN.Stein it do not align right if i change it to match_parent and blue bubble fill the entire row

Comment: @FrankN.Stein alignParentRight moving text to right side of the screen